# Why is $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z})/(a_1+a_2+a_3=0)\cong \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Why is $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z})/(a_1+a_2+a_3=0)\cong \mathbb{Z}$?

That is: What would be the isomorphism to see this? And, in general, is there a way to find an isomorphism $G/N\cong H$? The  isomorphm theorems don't seem to be applicable?

Comment: You mean the subgroup $N$ consisting of all triples $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ with $a_1+a_2+a_3=0$.

Comment: Yes. It's a little shorthand. I apologize. If i'm correct every subgroup of an abelian group is normal, so the quotient is defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First define a group homomorphism $\varphi \colon \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $\varphi(a_1,a_2,a_3) = a_1 + a_2 + a_3$. Note that this is surjective and $\text{ker} (\varphi) = \{ (a_1,a_2,a_3) \in \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \mid a_1 + a_2 + a_3 =0 \}$. Now you can conclude using the first isomorphism theorem, which gives you an explicit isomorphism.

This is the usual strategy to prove that $G/N \cong H$: find a surjective group homomorphism $G \to H$ with kernel $N$.

Comment: Thank you! Pretty straightforward.